# AttributeError: module 'h5py.tests.old' has no attribute 'MODULES'

Tags: python

I was trying to run a python tool called "read_fast5_basecaller.py". It throws an error which is "AttributeError: module 'h5py.tests.old' has no attribute 'MODULES'"

```
read_fast5_basecaller.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kokep/bin/bin/read_fast5_basecaller.py", line 73, in <module>
    from albacore.fast5_fastq_data_handler import Fast5FastQDataHandler
  File "/home/kokep/bin/lib/python3.6/site-packages/albacore/fast5_fastq_data_handler.py", line 14, in <module>
    from albacore.fast5_data_handler import Fast5DataHandler
  File "/home/kokep/bin/lib/python3.6/site-packages/albacore/fast5_data_handler.py", line 15, in <module>
    from albacore.read_metadata import ReadMetadata
  File "/home/kokep/bin/lib/python3.6/site-packages/albacore/read_metadata.py", line 5, in <module>
    from ont_fast5_api.fast5_file import Fast5File
  File "/home/kokep/bin/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ont_fast5_api/fast5_file.py", line 5, in <module>
    import h5py
  File "/home/kokep/bin/lib/python3.6/site-packages/h5py/__init__.py", line 62, in <module>
    from .tests import run_tests
  File "/home/kokep/bin/lib/python3.6/site-packages/h5py/tests/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    MODULES = old.MODULES + hl.MODULES
AttributeError: module 'h5py.tests.old' has no attribute 'MODULES'
```

I was wondering if old module of h5py is needed. Should I install the older version of the h5py module? Thank you.